# Generar un archivo de Excel con datos de un DataGridView con campos nulos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, excel, datagridview

Estoy intentando generar un archivo de excel en base a los datos de un datagridview pero cuando ejecuto el metodo me parece el mensaje "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Añadi la referencia Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library ademas que en mi datagridview algunos campos estan nulos, como arreglar eso?

```
//Metodo de excel
    private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            aplicacion.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que comentas, el problema está en esta línea

```
hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()
```

En esta línea das por seguro que grd.Rows[i].Cells[j] tiene un valor, cuando tú mismo estás diciendo que hay algunas celdas que pueden no tener o que están vacías.

Por lo tanto, controla si la celda tiene valor. En caso que tenga pues pones el valor y, en caso contrario, pones el campo vacío.

```
for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    if (grd.Rows[i].Cells[j] != null)
    {
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    } else {
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = "";
    }
}
```

O lo que también puedes hacer es inicializar siempre el campo con el campo vacío, y en caso que en esa posición tenga valor, pues pones el valor. Es mucho más limpio que no hacer if...else.

```
for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = "";

    if (grd.Rows[i].Cells[j] != null)
    {
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Me sigue marcando error en ests linrd "hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(); " de los 2 ejemplos